# Using iTunes in Windows VM under Linux

Tags: windows, linux, itunes, virtual-machine

I'm thinking about switching from Windows to Linux when I get a new laptop. As far as I can tell, the only software I use that doesn't run on Linux or have a Linux equivalent is iTunes.

Here are the tasks that I currently use iTunes for:

- Syncing my iPhone a few times a week (for podcasts, keeping smart playlists up-to-date etc);
- Downloading podcasts;
- Using Home Sharing to sync purchases to another machine on my home network.

Would I still be able to perform these tasks using iTunes in a Windows VM?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you could't

Comment: Well, does device passthrough work properly for the iPhone? Will the Bonjour service used to find other Home Sharing devices on the network work correctly? I'd like some evidence that it works before I start.

Comment: Can't tell about that, I don't have any Apple device. But usually a VM is the same thing as a real computer, except a bit slower. USB and Network will work like a computer on a network.

Comment: I just read an ubuntu forum, in French and they are telling that everything in iTunes is working perfectly in a VM. And found that in english : http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/77025.aspx

Comment: There is no reason why iTunes wouldn't work perfectly as far as I know.. it is just a software application that interacts with a USB device that can be directly connected in to the VM. If it had to interface directly though something like PCI-E then you would have issues.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/797570/333341

Answer (score 0):

I've never tested this personally, but I can tell you the VirtualBox claims support for networking and USB passthrough. You shouldn't have any problems with it. You could always dual boot and try it out first, if you're not sure.

Comment: USB support has been a bit iffy for me in VirtualBox; your mileage may vary.